# Novice: How can I learn how to build GLEW with MinGW?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, gcc, build

I'm a daft C/C++ novice using Windows, building with MinGW through console. I have been looking for days on how to build GLEW so that I can statically link it with my incredibly simple SDL+OpenGL program. For static linking, GLEW supposedly requires a special lib apart from lglew32 called lglew32s, and this is what I cannot get my hands on.

I'm trying to learn to use gcc/g++ right now, and to understand the options and the whole preprocess/compile/link thing in general. I'm about 5% there. I found some GLEW building batch file examples around the net, most being pretty old, but even one of them that was new didn't compile lglew32s for me, so I can dynamically link but I can't statically link.

So because I can't find glew32s.lib anywhere online built with anything other than VS, I have to learn to understand what this means and somehow figure out how to compile glew32s with what I've learned from it:

```
gcc.exe -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude  -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.o -c src/glew.c
gcc.exe -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a    -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -nostdlib
ar.exe cr lib/libglew32.a src/glew.o
gcc.exe -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_MX -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude  -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.mx.o -c src/glew.c
gcc.exe  -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32mx.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32mx.dll.a -o lib/glew32mx.dll src/glew.mx.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -nostdlib
ar.exe cr lib/libglew32mx.a src/glew.mx.o
```

I have learned to compile my own .cpp and .c projects using gcc/g++ (again I'm barely out of the "hello world" phase in terms of actual code), and also how to dynamically link them to the SDL and GLEW libraries. I understand very well now what this all means:

```
g++ sdlglew.cpp -o sdlglew -Wall -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lglew32 -lopengl32 -I "C:\SDL2-2.0.9\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2" -L "C:\SDL2-2.0.9\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" -mwindows
```

(My SDL stuff is off in its own directory. GLEW's headers and libs are in MinGW's dir)

I think I need either -DGLEW_STATIC in my command OR #define GLEW_STATIC in my sdlglew.cpp to compile GLEW statically, but those options with lglew32 give me no errors upon compile and fail to start due to the missing glew32.dll. Compiler spits out errors with -static because SDL has not been set up for it yet.

Basically, if you have any resources on understanding what exactly the mentioned compile script is doing per line and how I could build glew32s, I'd be real happy :S I want to understand it, but it really seems like there's no documentation on it for us newbies

Comment: Note that the accepted answer on that duplicate seems unnecessarily complicated and doesn't result in a static build, though.  (Some of the lower voted answers seem like they could offer some good advice though)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the Makefile? (It should be included in the MinGW evironment, I think)

In which case I think you should just be able to do something along the lines of:

```
cd thefolderwithmakefile
make all GLEW_STATIC=1
```

Then you need to define GLEW_STATIC ( as you said by `-DGLEW_STATIC` or by `#define GLEW_STATIC` )when you are building your project files as well.